# Searching an external API through a rails form and displaying the results in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, search

I need to search data (tutorials) from an external API with 2 params (tag and device) provided by a form in my rails app.

In my routes I have:

```
resources :search_lists, only: [:index] do
  collection do
    post :search
  end
end
```

Here's what I think I should put in my `SearchListsController`:

```
def index
  @search_parameter = params[:tags]
end

def search
end
```

I'm not sure how I would organize my code and where I should pass the API calls.

Here's my view, rails doesn't recognize the `search_lists_url`:

```
<form action="<%= search_lists_url %>">
  <input type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="Search by tag">
  <label >Filters:</label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="first_checkbox">Smarthpone
  <input type="checkbox" value="second_checkbox">Tablet
  <input type="checkbox" value="third_checkbox">Mac
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Can anyone help me please ? :)

Comment: Your API calls will go in the controller, in the search action.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an external API, your API consumer does not recognize the API application's route helpers. A better way would be to have the form action call a url for a controller action in the consumer application and then handle the API call on this controller action.

For example on your API consumer application you can have this in your routes:

```
post "search_lists" => "lists#search", as: :search
```

then have a `lists_controller.rb` file in your `controllers` directory with a search action like this:

```
 class ListsController < ApplicationController
     include HTTParty

     def search
     ## make your API Call on this action
      response = HTTParty.post(your_api_host_url/search_lists/search, {body: [#your form input data##]})
     end
 end
```

You can parse the returned JSON into a ruby array and show it in your view.
In the example i have used the HTTParty gem for making HTTP request, you can use other available ruby libraries to accomplish the same.

Your form can now look like this:

```
<%= form_tag search_path, method: :post do %>
  <%#= Your input tags %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me: still doesn't recognize the search_path. In the routes, did you mean "lists_search#search" ?

Comment: The route was just an example. You can use your own routes and controller names. The point to note is that you need to make the api call on the controller and parse the response.